# Visual Sutdio 2015 Installation Error

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio

EDIT: I got it working, for some reason seems uninstalling XNA Framework got it working, the other frameworks didn't even matter, I didn't suspect XNA since it came with a different program but oh well, atleast it works now.

Ever Since I updated my Windows 10 I can't get Visual studio to intall, each time I try to install it, I get this: http://prntscr.com/c6cuib no matter what options I check in the installation box, I ran it as an administrator, have no antivirus active, disabled windows firewall, troubleshooted windows update, all for nothing.

I once got it to install but it was not useable: http://prnt.sc/c6cfb3

Any ideas?

EDIT: The errors from the log file:

```
Error 0x80070002: Failed to move verified file to complete payload path:
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DE064F60-6522-3310-9665-B5E3E78B3638}v14.0.23107
\packages\communitycore\Setup\cab6.cab

Error 0x80070002: Failed to cache payload: cab4F7DEE837DFF7D88E4EA825A6F68F405

MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_communitycore) failed: Error Message Id: 1317 ErrorMessage: Error 1317.An error occurred while attempting to create the directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2

Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.

MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:Error 1317.An error occurred while attempting to create the directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2 Result Detail:0 Restart:None

 Error Message=Error 1317.An error occurred while attempting to create the directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=vs_communitycore

Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.

Error 0x80070643: UX aborted cache verify begin
```

Comment: The installer's log indicates the reason it failed.  Can you provide that reason?

Comment: From the bottom to the top these are the first errors I can see:
[18D8:1FCC][2016-08-16T13:52:07]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[18D8:1FCC][2016-08-16T13:52:07]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[2210:0F00][2016-08-16T13:52:07]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.

But I am not too good at reading logs.

Comment: I can't read I errors that are not formatted.

Comment: I also found ExecuteError: Package (vs_communitycore) failed: Error Message Id: 1303 ErrorMessage: Error 1303.The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2.  The installation cannot continue.  Log on as administrator or contact your system administrator. How is this error even there? I am administrator of my system, I placed the installer on my C: drive where I'm also installing VS and I always run it as an administrator, I went to that directory and the folder isn't even there!

Comment: It isn't there because of a permission problem hence the reason it generated the error and the installation rolled back.  *I cannot read errors in comments.*

Comment: First, ensure that your VS2015 installation source is not corrupted. If you are trying to install from an ISO image, you can verify the checksum of ISO against the number that Microsoft has provided to ensure that it is not corrupted. See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-iso-sha1-vs.aspx

Comment: Those seem to be all the error messages: http://prnt.sc/c6d7qq , http://prnt.sc/c6d87i , http://prnt.sc/c6d90q

Comment: I got my installer from https://www.visualstudio.com/ by dowloading Community 2015.

Comment: no idea but where it says "An error occurred while attempting to create the directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2" <-- are you able to create that directory manually?

Comment: Yes, I am, and when I did and then tried to install VS again I got the same error, or a similar one atleast.

Comment: If you are sure that your installation is not corrupted, try to create another user with admin privileges and install VS, it might be a problem related to your windows profile.

Comment: @ShadowTerror maybe try deleting that directory and then try to install again

Comment: @barlop By default the installer doesn't create it, and it says it can't, if I create the installer manually, it still can't use it, if I delete it and try to install again we are back at the beginning.

Comment: @ShadowTerror have you tried googling "failed to move verified file to complete payload path"  then trying a bunch of suggestions from that, and also try going to add/remove programs and try to uninstall anything .net  e.g. any .net frameworks, and anything visual studio related

Comment: @barlop I tried removing/repairing eveything that came with Visual Studio and even anything related, restarted the PC and tried again, no luck.

Comment: @ShadowTerror do a search for "frame" in add/remove programs and lots of microsoft .net frameworks will show up, then remove them all

Comment: Check this,it might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/33881460

Comment: Verify your user has the proper permissions to  `..\ProgramData`,your user not having the proper permissions for reasons yet to be determined, would explain the reason the installer would be unable to create a folder in that directory.  Be sure you are installing Visual Studio by mounting the .ISO, since you are running Windows 10, this will avoid the online installer most people use and in turn have problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling XNA Framework worked in my case, but a good thing to try is search for "frame" in Programs and features and uninstall anything related, then proceed installing Visual Studio, as recommended by @barlop in the comments.